# Check if scanner input equals list that is converted to arraylist

Tags: java, list

I have a file with a bunch of strings in it. I have converted whatever is in that file to a list. Now I want to create a scanner that scans for user-input and returns true or false whether that scanner input contains whatever is in the list (file).

I have the logic in my head but I don't know the syntax.

I have come this far. I need help. Thanks in advance.

```
public static void main (String [] args) throws Exception {

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("/Users/Greg/workspace/erlang/fred.txt"));
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    while (scan.hasNext()){
        list.add(scan.next());
        Scanner scan2 = new Scanner (System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter");

        String input = scan2.nextLine();

       // if input equals list / file - > sysout true . else > false

}
```

By the help of the amazing people on stackoverflow I completed my assignment. The finished code is this and it is working perfectly:¨

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("/Users/Greg/workspace/erlang/fred.txt"));
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    while (scan.hasNext()) {
        list.add(scan.next());

    }
    do {
    String input = null;

    Scanner scan2 = new Scanner(System.in);

    input = scan2.nextLine();
    if (list.contains(input)) {
        System.out.println("Yes, List/File contains: " + input);
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("No, List/File does not contain: " + input);
    }
    } while (true);

}

{

}

{

}
```

Comment: what version of Java are you using? 5,6,7,8? just curious.

Comment: Check if scanner input equals list that is converted to arraylist?
What you really want to do? If I am getting you correct, you want to check if user given input exists in the List or not. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly correct. I did the if statements. If (input.equals (list)) etc but its not working.

Answer (score 0):

I created a `BufferedReader` that reads in input from `System.in` and then checked if the list contains the line that was read in, and wrote it out accordingly.

```
public static void main (String [] args) throws Exception {    
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("/Users/Greg/workspace/erlang/fred.txt"));
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    while (scan.hasNext()){
        list.add(scan.next());

    BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
    String line = null;
    try
    {
        bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        do
        {
            line = bufferedReader.readLine();
            System.out.println("" + list.contains(line));
        }
        while(!"exit".equals(line));
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {
        if(bufferedReader != null) try { bufferedReader.close(); } catch(IOException e) {}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main (String [] args) throws Exception {

Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("/Users/Greg/workspace/erlang/fred.txt"));
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
while (scan.hasNext()){
    list.add(scan.next());
 }

BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));


try {
        System.out.println("EnterValue : ");
        String s = br.readLine();
        while (!s.equals("quit")) {
            System.out.println("EnterValue : ");
            boolean flag = false;
            for (String value : list) {
                if (value.equals(s)) {
                    flag = true;
                    break;
                }
                if (flag) {
                    System.out.println("true");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("false");
                }

            }
            s = br.readLine();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
```